# Generate a separate CSV record for each array element

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have a JSON:

```
{
  "Country": "USA",
  "State": "TX",
  "Employees": [
    {
      "Name": "Name1",
      "address": "SomeAdress1"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "Country": "USA",
  "State": "FL",
  "Employees": [
    {
      "Name": "Name2",
      "address": "SomeAdress2"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Name3",
      "address": "SomeAdress3"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "Country": "USA",
  "State": "CA",
  "Employees": [
    {
      "Name": "Name4",
      "address": "SomeAdress4"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to use jq to get the following result in csv format:

Country, State, Name, Address

```
USA, TX, Name1, SomeAdress1
USA, FL, Name2, SomeAdress2
USA, FL, Name3, SomeAdress3
USA, CA, Name4, SomeAdress4
```

I have got the following jq:

```
jq -r '.|[.Country,.State,(.Employees[]|.Name,.address)] | @csv'
```

And I get the following with 2nd line having more columns than required. I want these extra columns in a separate row:

```
"USA","TX","Name1","SomeAdress1"
"USA","FL","Name2","SomeAdress2","Name3","SomeAdress3"
"USA","CA","Name4","SomeAdress4"
```

And I want the following result:

```
"USA","TX","Name1","SomeAdress1"
"USA","FL","Name2","SomeAdress2"
"USA","FL","Name3","SomeAdress3"
"USA","CA","Name4","SomeAdress4"
```

Comment: @oguzismail I was expecting similar questions here, but wasn't able to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a separate array for each employee.

```
[.Country, .State] + (.Employees[] | [.Name, .address]) | @csv
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JZVwgNVWgp)</sup>

Comment: I have accepted this answer as this works with my containerised jq. @andlr  answer also works fine TBF, but in case if using a jq as a container in a build pipeline, it will require further tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

You can store root object in a variable, and then expand the Employees arrays:

```
$ jq -r '. as $root | .Employees[]|[$root.Country, $root.State, .Name, .address] | @csv'
"USA","TX","Name1","SomeAdress1"
"USA","FL","Name2","SomeAdress2"
"USA","FL","Name3","SomeAdress3"
"USA","CA","Name4","SomeAdress4"
```

Comment: This answer works for me, but not in a pipeline where I am restricted to use a container for jq.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, but I want to talk about why your attempt doesn't work, as well as why it seems like it should.

You are wondering why this:

```
jq -r '.|[.Country,.State,(.Employees[]|.Name,.address)] | @csv'
```

produces this:

```
"USA","TX","Name1","SomeAdress1"
"USA","FL","Name2","SomeAdress2","Name3","SomeAdress3"
"USA","CA","Name4","SomeAdress4"
```

perhaps because this:

```
jq '{Country:.Country,State:.State,Name:(.Employees[]|.Name)}'
```

produces this:

```
{
  "Country": "USA",
  "State": "TX",
  "Name": "Name1"
}
{
  "Country": "USA",
  "State": "FL",
  "Name": "Name2"
}
{
  "Country": "USA",
  "State": "FL",
  "Name": "Name3"
}
{
  "Country": "USA",
  "State": "CA",
  "Name": "Name4"
}
```

It turns out the difference is in what exactly `[...]` and `{...}` do in a `jq` filter. In  the array constructor `[...]`, the entire contents of the square brackets, commas and all, is a single filter, which is fully evaluated and all the results combined into one array. Each comma inside is simply the sequencing operator, which means generate all the values from the filter on its left, then all the values from the filter on its right. In contrast, the commas in the `{...}` object constructor *are* part of the syntax and just separate the fields of the object. If any of the field expressions yield multiple values then multiple whole objects are produced. If *multiple* field expressions yield multiple value then you get a whole object for every *combination* of yielded values.

When you do this:

```
jq -r '.|[.Country,.State,(.Employees[]|.Name,.address)] | @csv'
                  ^      ^                   ^
                  1      2                   3
```

the problem is that the commas labelled "1", "2" and "3" are all doing the same thing, evaluating all the values for the filter on the left, then all the values for the filter on the right. Then the array constructor catches all of them and produces a single array. The array constructor will never create more than one array for one input.

So with that in mind, you need to make sure that where you're expanding out `.Employees[]` *isn't inside* your array constructor. Here's another option to add to the answers you already have:

```
jq -r '.Employee=.Employees[]|[.Country,.State,.Employee.Name,.Employee.address]|@csv'
```

[demo](https://jqplay.org/s/oNKKIqLtNk)

or indeed:

```
jq -r '.Employees[] as $e|[.Country,.State,$e.Name,$e.address]|@csv'
```

[demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JP-5c8tk_-)

Comment: The manual explains all this in a single sentence under [Array construction](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Arrayconstruction:[]): *All of the results produced by all of the expressions are collected into one big array.*